# PC File server variable performance when importing from Access MDB

Tags: sas

I've got some code that runs in Enterprise guide (SAS Enterprise build, Windows locally, Unix server), which imports a large table via a local install of PC File server. It runs fine for me, but is slow to the point of uselessness for the system tester.

When I use his SAS identity on my windows PC, the code works; but when I use my SAS identity on his machine it doesn't, so it appears to be a problem with the local machine. We have the same version of EG (same hot fixes installed) connecting to the same server (with the same roles) running the same code in the same project, connecting to the same Access database.

Even a suggestion of what to test next would be greatly appreciated!

```
libname ACCESS_DB pcfiles path="&db_path"
    server=&_CLIENTMACHINE
    port=9621;

data permanent.&output_table (keep=[lots of vars]);
    format [lots of vars];
    length [lots of vars];
    set ACCESS_DB.&source_table (rename=([some awkward vars])); 
    if [var]=[value];
    [build some new vars, nothing scary];
;
run;
```

*Addenda* The PC files server is running on the same machine where the EG project is being run in both case - we both have the same version installed. &db_path is the location of the Access database - on a network file store both users can access (in fact other, smaller tables can be retrieved by both users in a sensible amount of time). This server is administered by IT and not a server we as the business can get software installed on.

Comment: Unfortunately after multiple fix attempts guided by support, ticket closed unresolved. It is most likely caused by an infrastructure problem I am not in a position to diagnose or resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution of your problem will require more details and best solved by dialog with SAS Tech Support.  The "online ticket" form is [here](http://support.sas.com/ctx/supportform//createForm) or you can call them by phone.

For example, is the PCFILES server running locally on both your machine and your tester's machine?  If yes, is the file referenced by &db_path on a network file server and does your tester have similar access (meaning both of you can reach it the same way)?  Have you considered installing the PCFILE server on your file server rather than on your local PC?  Too many questions, I think, for a forum like this.  But I could be wrong (its happened before); perhaps others will have a great answer.

Comment: Hi Bob. I've since raised a SAS ticket. When it gets resolved, assuming it's okay I'll update here and credit SAS with the answer. On the off chance anyone else has run into this before I will update the question with a few more details.